# Is it possible to animate slideDown on visibility hidden element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make SlideDown or an alternative of that effect to a `nav` that is bu default `visibilty:hidden` and what i'm doing now is like this:

```
$(this).find('nav.Menu').css('visibility','visible')
```

It's working just fine, but i have more submenus and i want an effect when hovering between the main menu to slidedown and up submenus. is this possible without `display:none/block` ?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sou5rjon/1/)

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle?

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @atmd what do you mean? i've tried only making it visible and hidden by `.css` in jQuery

Comment: Also please post some html

Comment: jQuery generally prefers the `display` property. What advantage are you gaining by using `visibility` that justifies the increased complexity of your code?

Comment: you said it works with `css('visibility','visible')` and ask it its possible with `css('display','none')`

Comment: @IonicăBizău please see jsfiddle

Comment: @JDB, you are absolutely right, but my nav that is hidden has a sub nav that is a sidebar which should be visible, so if i hide by `display` the first nav then i couldn't show the child nav, that's why i'm using `visibility`

Comment: @atmd i'm asking to make slideDown animation with and element that is `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your element has `visibility: hidden` make it `visible`, then `hide()` it and call the `slideDown()` function:

```
$('#error').css('visibility','visible').hide().slideDown();
```

[**JSFDIDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sou5rjon/2/)

The hover handlers can be:

```
$("<selector>").hover(function () {
    $('#error').css('visibility','visible').hide().stop().slideDown();
}, function () {
    $('#error').stop().slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Ionica that's amazing, and if i want the reverse animation, will it work with : `show().slideUp()`? i'm asking because my behavior will be applied on `mouseover' and `mouseout`, thanks a lot~

Comment: @Ionica do you have any idea how to accomplish this drop down man? http://www.tntrailsandbyways.com/  thanks a lot

Comment: @Jimmy Isn't it working? What's the unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can try positioning your submenu so it is behind its parent, toggle the visibility, and slide it out from behind the parent. You can reverse the process (slide behind, then toggle visibility) when closing the submenu.